# UserControl examples

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight, user-controls, wpf-controls

I am new to the WPF.

I wanted to create a UserControl which contains two fields for example

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="189*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="328*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="53*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="64*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="62*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="141*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Name:" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>

    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Right" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Age:" VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
    <Button Content="Add Person" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="75" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>

</Grid>
```

I wanted to create my user control in such a way that other developers(Who uses my usercontrol) can be able to add extra fields to it.

Imagine a developer want to add "Address filed to the above control".

If any one have sample articles on this please provide me.

Comment: I'm not sure that what you want, is really feasible with a user control. You probably want to create a custom control to handle this, and then style it accordingly to include the pre-defined UI elements you want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after [ContentControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). See below article for an example.

> The ContentControl can contain any type of common language runtime
>   object (such as a string or a DateTime object) or a UIElement object
>   (such as a Rectangle or a Panel). This enables you to add rich content
>   to controls such as Button and CheckBox.

[How to Embed Arbitrary Content in a WPF Control](http://www.ikriv.com/dev/wpf/displayingcontent/index.html)